# iterating over array of dicts doens't work properly

Tags: javascript

Could someone please explain what is going on here? How can I retrieve at least `1`?

```
$> for (var i in [{a: 1, b: "ok"}]) { console.log(i); }
0
```

Comment: That's an array of a single dict. The array is being iterated for its indices. The index of the first, the only and the last value in the array is `0`.

Comment: Have a look at the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to learn how `for...in` works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `for ... in` loops loop over the **keys** of the object. You passed an array with one element (element 0), so you get 0.

If you do this:

```
for (var i in {a: 1, b: "ok"}) { console.log(i); }
```

you'll get "a" and "b". The difference is the brackets you have. That makes the object an array with a single value, that value being the "a - b" object.

If you want to get at the *values* in the object, you need to get them. Unfortunately, that's kind-of tricky when you start from an object literal, as there's no way to reference it. You could put it in a variable:

```
var obj = {a: 1, b: "ok"};
for (var i in obj) { console.log(obj[i]); }
```

*edit* — if you want to keep it a single "clean" statement without that pesky local variable:

```
(function(obj) {
  for (var i in obj) { console.log(obj[i]); }
})( {a: 1, b: "ok"} );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var dicts = [{a: 1, b: "ok"}];

for (var i in dicts) { console.log(dicts[i]); }
//yields {a: 1, b: "ok"}

for (var i in dicts) { console.log(dicts[i]['a']); }
//yields 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to save all of the information by parking your {} into a variable.

```
c = {a:1,b:'ok'};
for(var i in c){console.log(c[i])};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var dict_array = [{a: 1, b: "ok"}];
for (var i = 0; i < dict_array.length; i++) {
    for (var key in dict_array[i]) {
        console.log(key + ':' + dict_array[i][key]);
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
a:1
b:ok
```